# Repeat string until end of line

Tags: html, css

As the title says,

I need to repeat a string of unknown length for full available width without breaking into a new line.

To explain a bit better the code ∙ • ●● • ∙  should be repeated until it reaches the green line

[image: see image]

but this shouldn't happen

[image: see image]

Comment: Trying to find out screen's width is not PHP's job

Answer (score 6):

**Not possible.** What you are asking to do is using something on the server side, but the screen's width and height are in the client side and are unknown to the server. But what you can do is, using CSS, you can hide the overflowing content.

> **PHP is a server side language and has no relation with client side stuff. Use CSS for client side stuff.**

**Alternate Solution:** Use CSS.

A basic example of what you would rather try to achieve is:

```css
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p> ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙ ∙ • ●● • ∙</p>
```